# Attempting to play media with onclicklistener, when I click app crashes

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I click the button the ducks mediaplayer file should start, but the app just crashes.
  Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button ducksplay, ducksstop;
MediaPlayer ducks;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ducksplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ducksplay);
    ducksstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ducksstop);
    ducksplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ducks.start();
        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: please share the Exception in Log? where is the ducks reference is initialize? may be that is the problem

Comment: Refer this Link : http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-mediaplayer-sample-code-walkthrough-on-intel-architecture you need to initialize media player before start

Comment: Thank you, I added "MediaPlayer ducks = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ducks);" to the activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is really the whole class it will crash because you have no MediaPlayer instance, it is a null pointer. Otherwise than in C++ in Java an Object variable is always a reference, initialized with null.

So you will need a ducks = new MediaPlayer() in onCreate

---

Then a MediaPlayer has an internal state-machine that must be followed

The minimum you must do for local playback is:

1. Instanciate a MediaPlayer Object
2. setDataSouce on the player object
3. prepare the player object
4. start

The minimum you must do for remote playback is:

1. Instanciate a MediaPlayer Object
2. setDataSouce on the player object
3. setOnPreparedListener on the player object
4. asyncPrepare the player object
5. wait for the onPreparedListener is called
6. in that listener call start on the player object

As reference please take a look at the MediaPalyer state diagram:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

And **never forget to instanciate objects also for your class member references in Java**, otherwise they are null.